# What is wrong with Undefined function A? (lisp)

Tags: loops, lisp, common-lisp, undefined-function

Have to write a program that asks the user for input until they input 0. Then must output the minimum value for number that were inputted. I am new to lisp and i keep getting undefined function A in the console but a is a variable in the code.

```
(defun find_min ( x y )
  (if(< x y)
     (+ x 0)
     (+ y 0)))

(defun minOfNums()
  (loop 
     (princ "Enter number: ")
     (setq a (read))        
     (princ "Enter number: ")
     (setq min (find_min (a (read))))
     (terpri)
     (when (= a 0) (return a)))
  (write min))
```

(minOfNums)

Comment: what lead you to add zero to x and y in the first function? why are you doing a loop? also please note that `min` undefined, you should introduce the variable with a `let` binding probably

Comment: Variables a and min are undefined. (a ...) is a function call, where the function is undefined. Output maybe buffered, thus print and then read is not sufficient in general.

Answer (score 3):

In `(setq min (find_min (a (read))))` you are calling the function `a` with the result of reading an object from the user. It should (probably) be `(setq min (find_min a (read)))` instead.

If nothing else, the `find_min` function expects two arguments and the code as written only passes one.